# Taking user input from a prompt, searching an array of images and displaying the image the user has found [javaScript]]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, prompt

Essentially, I am trying to search an array with user input from a prompt, and display an image based off of the users search.

Currently I have been trying this method and I'm sure it is correct, although I am unsure if it is honestly.

My html looks like this:

```
        <label>Specific slide</label>
        <button id="submit" onclick="specificSLIDE()">enter a specific slide</button>
```

My javascript which interacts with the button looks like this (very messy):

```
function specificSLIDE(){

var ImageSearch = prompt("Enter a specific slide you would like to view", "<slide goes here>");
var ARRAYSEARCH = "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide"+ImageSearch+".jpg";
if(ImageSearch!= null){
//        document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = imageArray.find(ImageSearch);
   // document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = imageArray.find(ARRAYSEARCH);
    document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = '<img src='+imageArray(ARRAYSEARCH)+'id="slide">';
    console.log(ImageSearch);
}else{
    prompt("PLEASE ENTER A VALUE");
}
}
```

the result should output into this html element:

```
imgStart[0].innerHTML = '<img  src="../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide1.jpg" id = "slide">';
```

my array:

```
var c = 0,imageArray = ["../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide1.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide2.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide3.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide4.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide5.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide6.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide7.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide8.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide9.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide10.jpg", "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide11.jpg"];
```

I'm aware this is probably a really inefficient way of searching the array but it was one of the better solutions I was able to come up with although it doesn't quite work.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: how do your array looks like? imageArray(ARRAYSEARCH)  is a function call , can you post your function imageArray?

Comment: Just edited there, my bad

Comment: ok in order to have a value of an array item you call it like this array[indexofElementinArray]. In your example you already have the value ARRAYSEARCH, so you only have to check if it exists in the array

Comment: I gave up trying to make this readable - Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] and get rid of all the waffle. Far too much text that is irrelevant to the explanation and the issue. Remember to click TIDY before saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments:
ok in order to have a value of an array item you call it like this array[indexofElementinArray]. In your example you already have the value ARRAYSEARCH, so you only have to check if it exists in the array.
So:

```
function specificSLIDE(){

var ImageSearch = prompt("Enter a specific slide you would like to view", "<slide goes here>");
var ARRAYSEARCH = "../Clientside/Sampledata/Single Page Architecture (SPA)/Slide"+ImageSearch+".jpg";
if(ImageSearch && imageArray.indexOf(ARRAYSEARCH)!== -1){
//        document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = imageArray.find(ImageSearch);
   // document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = imageArray.find(ARRAYSEARCH);
    document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = '<img src='+ARRAYSEARCH+'id="slide">';
    console.log(ImageSearch);
}else{
    prompt("PLEASE ENTER A VALUE");
}
}
```